# Need to covert the following code to json

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following dojo code in my program , and i would like to pass the values      such as code,client.key,date_joined as json. and below i have my script

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <a href="/api/client/{{ client.key }}">{{ client.name }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
       <form method="get" action="/api/authorize">
       <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/client   /{{client.key}}/" />  
       <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code" />
       <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="{{client.key}}" />
       <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="date_joined" /> 
       <input type="submit" value="Request" />
       </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need the help to convert the above code's arguments to json and i have the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.authenticate').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = this.id.replace("_", "");
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        dataType: "jsonp",

        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    },
        success: function(data) {
        var response = [];
        for(key in data){
        response.push(key + ":" + data[key]);
                     }
        alert(response.join('\n'));
                      },
             });
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: dont flag dojo while running jquery engine huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.authenticate').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var token = this.id.replace("_", "");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/client",
                dataType: "json",
                data: '{"Client.key":"'+your value+'"}',
                //beforeSend: function(xhr){  
                // xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); 
                // },  
                success: function (data) {
                    //var response = [];      
                    //for(key in data){     
                    //response.push(key + ":" + data[key]);   
                    //  alert(response.join('\n'));  
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

little modification for your code, if sending json object mention datatype as json and follow the json object format. 
for more information on json objects try http://www.json.org/